# ¿Puedo generar un archivo PDF en c# sin necesidad de tener una base de datos?

Tags: c#

Estoy por realizar un proyecto el cual tiene forma de reporte, mi cliente me pide que pueda exportarlo como PDF con el simple hecho de dar click en el botón de guardar, quiero saber si es posible hacerlo sin necesidad de una base de datos.

Comment: Cuando dices sin necesidad de una base de datos, te refieres a sin utilizar Reporting Services?

Comment: puedes usar itextsharp, busca informacion sobre esta libreria e intenta programarlo, si no lo consigues pon tu codigo y veremos como poder ayudarte.

Comment: puedes crear la plantilla del reporte con crystal reports, enviar la data como parametros y exportar en formato pdf, word, excel, etc

Comment: puedes usar el objeto reportviewer de VS, solo arrastralo a tu formulario y agrega un nuevo reporte rdlc

Answer (score 0):

Si , puede utilizar rdlc puedes enviar valores como parámetros y en el reporte solo ubicas donde deseas visualizarlo

```
  ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
        string msg = "hola mundo";
        ReportParameter[] parametro= new ReportParameter[1]; 
        parametro[0] = new ReportParameter("p1", msg ); 
        reportViewer.LocalReport.DisplayName = "NuevoReporte";
        reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + @"reporte\reporte.rdlc";
        byte[] bytes = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF");
```

Answer (score -1):

Si yo en lo personal uso una API bien sencilla llamada ItextSharp que si usas VS2013 o superior lo puedes descargar gratuitamente desde nuget y si quieres aca te doy un pequeño ejemplo de como usarlo:

```
   Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
   PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("NombreDeTuArchivo.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));
   document.Open();
   document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
   document.Close();
   writer.Close();
   Response.ContentType = "pdf/application";
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
   "attachment;filename=First PDF document.pdf");
   Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
```